# Adding users to AD using LDAP

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm writing an application that will add users to Active Directory. I'm trying to use this code to connect to the "Users" shared folder in AD

```
LDAP://celtestdomdc1.celtestdom.local/CN=Users,DC=celtestdom,DC=local
```

However it adds the user in with the shared folders, instead of within the "Users" shared folder. Shouldn't CN=Users mean it will add it to the "Users" folder?

Thanks

Comment: I think marc_s is correct in your case. If you post some code, we might be able to show you the changes that would be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a user, you need to

- bind to the container you want to create the user in
- create the new user account as a child of that container

Just by setting the LDAP path, you are **not** defining where the user will go!

Try something like this (C# sample - should be trivial to convert to VB.NET):

```
DirectoryEntry cnUsers = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Users,DC=celtestdom,DC=local");

// create a user directory entry in the container
DirectoryEntry newUser = container.Children.Add("cn=NewUserAccount", "user");

// add the samAccountName mandatory attribute
newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "NewUser";

// add any optional attributes
newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = "User";
newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = "One";

// save to the directory
newUser.CommitChanges();

// set a password for the user account
// using Invoke method and IadsUser.SetPassword
newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "pAssw0rdO1" });

// require that the password must be changed on next logon
newUser.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;

// save to the directory
newUser.CommitChanges();
```

Or if you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you could also use the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace that makes lots of things easier.

Then the code looks a bit simpler:

```
// create a context for a domain and define "base" container to use
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
         "celtestdom", "CN=Users,DC=celtestdom,DC=local");

// create a user principal object
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx, "NewUser", "pass@1w0rd01", true);

// assign some properties to the user principal
user.GivenName = "User";
user.Surname = "One";

// force the user to change password at next logon
user.ExpirePasswordNow();

// save the user to the directory
user.Save();
```

Check out more about the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)